# Как настроить шлюз на debian 9.5

Tags: debian, шлюз

Настроить шлюз, но не хочет давать интернет другим пк, раньше когда настраивал на Debian 9 все работала, а сейчас нет, почему?

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo eno1 eno2
iface lo inet loopback

# Wan
allow-hotplug eno1
iface eno1 inet dhcp


# Lan
iface eno2 inet static
        address 10.0.0.1
        netmask 255.255.255.248
        broadcast 10.0.0.7
        network 10.0.0.0
        dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

post-up /opt/scripts/gate.up

---------------------------------------

cat /opt/scripts/gate.up
#!/bin/sh
LAN_IP_RANGE="10.0.0.2/3"

iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F


echo 2 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eno1 -s $LAN_IP_RANGE -j MASQUERADE
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -s $LAN_IP_RANGE -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -d $LAN_IP_RANGE -j ACCEPT

-------------------------------

sysctl -p
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Comment: traceroute? tcpdump? logs?

Answer (score 0):

А где логи смотреть?

```
traceroute -T ya.ru
traceroute to ya.ru (87.250.250.242), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  78.107.125.57 (78.107.125.57)  0.331 ms  0.567 ms  0.560 ms
 2  10.2.254.182 (10.2.254.182)  0.993 ms  0.999 ms  1.211 ms
 3  hq-crs-be8.msk.corbina.net (195.14.62.166)  2.313 ms  2.037 ms  2.294 ms
 4  m9-crs-be3.corbina.net (195.14.54.141)  2.220 ms m9-crs-be14.msk.corbina.net (195.14.62.159)  1.935 ms m9-crs-be3.corbina.net (195.14.54.141)  2.426 ms
 5  m9-br-be1.corbina.net (195.14.54.79)  1.868 ms m9-br-be3.corbina.net (195.14.62.85)  2.137 ms m9-br-be1.corbina.net (195.14.54.79)  2.088 ms
 6  corbina-gw.dante.yandex.net (83.102.145.178)  2.684 ms  7.814 ms  5.946 ms
 7  sas1-c1-ae111.yndx.net (87.250.239.119)  8.162 ms ya.ru (87.250.250.242)  3.953 ms sas1-c1-ae22.yndx.net (87.250.239.6)  7.872 ms

 tcpdump
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eno1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
15:53:15.985011 IP ciberbox.ru.14785 > ppp158-255-178-140.pppoe.spdop.ru.15327: UDP, length 103
15:53:15.985820 IP ciberbox.ru.60391 > hdns2.corbina.net.domain: 61154+ PTR? 140.178.255.158.in-addr.arpa. (46)
15:53:16.042704 IP ciberbox.ru.53373 > lh-in-f198.1e100.net.https: Flags [P.], seq 1398765450:1398766125, ack 681721235, win 507, length 675
15:53:16.043995 IP ciberbox.ru.53373 > lh-in-f198.1e100.net.https: Flags [P.], seq 675:855, ack 1, win 507, length 180
15:53:16.044010 IP ciberbox.ru.53373 > lh-in-f198.1e100.net.https: Flags [P.], seq 855:928, ack 1, win 507, length 73
15:53:16.066285 IP lh-in-f198.1e100.net.https > ciberbox.ru.53373: Flags [.], ack 855, win 602, length 0
15:53:16.073027 IP lh-in-f198.1e100.net.https > ciberbox.ru.53373: Flags [P.], seq 1:78, ack 928, win 602, length 77
15:53:16.196259 IP ciberbox.ru.39842 > hdns2.corbina.net.domain: 62841+ PTR? 3.192.21.85.in-addr.arpa. (42)
15:53:16.198325 IP ciberbox.ru.33316 > hdns2.corbina.net.domain: 63035+ PTR? 198.161.233.64.in-addr.arpa. (45)
15:53:17.344180 Loopback, skipCount 0,  invalid (256)
15:53:17.835430 IP api.browser.yandex.ru.https > ciberbox.ru.53382: Flags [P.], seq 3399299092:3399299123, ack 601454643, win 11, length 31
15:53:17.835463 IP api.browser.yandex.ru.https > ciberbox.ru.53382: Flags [F.], seq 31, ack 1, win 11, length 0
15:53:17.835621 IP ciberbox.ru.58672 > hdns2.corbina.net.domain: 28894+ PTR? 82.250.250.87.in-addr.arpa. (44)
15:53:17.838822 IP hdns2.corbina.net.domain > ciberbox.ru.58672: 28894 1/0/0 PTR api.browser.yandex.ru. (79)
15:53:17.840627 IP ciberbox.ru.53382 > api.browser.yandex.ru.https: Flags [.], ack 32, win 509, length 0
15:53:17.851204 IP export-balancer.stable.qloud-b.yandex.net.https > ciberbox.ru.53381: Flags [P.], seq 1503720269:1503720300, ack 2576036369, win 137, length 31
15:53:17.851233 IP export-balancer.stable.qloud-b.yandex.net.https > ciberbox.ru.53381: Flags [F.], seq 31, ack 1, win 137, length 0
15:53:17.851367 IP ciberbox.ru.40882 > hdns2.corbina.net.domain: 47606+ PTR? 227.193.180.213.in-addr.arpa. (46)
```

Comment: Судя по трассировке всё отлично работает. И нужно было это добавить в вопрос, а не отвечать на него.

Comment: но ведь сервер не раздает интернет :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.1.1.1/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 33.33.33.33
```

Где `172.1.1.1/24` - локалка, `eth0` - интерфейс с интернетом, `33.33.33.33` - внешний `ip`, в вашем случае поставить `MASQUERADE`, `eth1` - - интерфейс с локалкой.

На локальном сервере в `Gateway` должена быть указана локальная `ip` твоего шлюза.